# Are their any default privilege in Oracle for users?

Tags: oracle, users, sysdba

I want to grant new users in Oracle the normal rules, for example, create a table, delete table update, in general, the default CRUD operations.
Every time I do this manually by running a grant script. Does Oracle come with default privilege group, for instance, create a user/schema with developer rules,
create a user with DBA rules, without using the grant statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a role and grant privileges to that role and in turn grant that role to a user.

To grant dba privileges to a user `grant dba to someuser`

You can explore default/current roles that gives you an idea.

```
select grantee role,privilege
from dba_sys_privs
where grantee not in (select username from dba_users)
-- and grantee in('DBA','CONNECT','RESOURCE')
group by grantee,privilege
order by 1
```

or

```
 -- dba_roles data dictionay lists all roles existing/created in Oracle
    select grantee role,privilege
    from dba_sys_privs
    where grantee in (select role from dba_roles)
    group by grantee,privilege
    order by 1
```

Keep in mind you have to be very careful before giving blanket privileges.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider that really helpful.